# Boot failure randomly. Can someone help?

Tags: boot, boot-failure

I often get stuck at the boot on battery.

I can suspend and hibernate without any trouble (even on battery).

If I plug the energy cable everything goes right *most of the time* (edited June 13).

Adding "acpi=off" doesn't solve the issue.

Disabling power save from LAN at BIOS doesn't solve this too.

[image]

Memory test seems to be ok:

[image]

I can even compile a kernel without a problem:

[image]

Has someone a tip for this?
(I have the same questions marks in my mind as the image shows if not more :-/ )

*obs.: this is an upgraded installation from Natty alpha.*
edited I (May 22):  I've installed a brand new final 11.04 and got the bug again.

edited II (June 13): I thought it was solved but it is not. After spending eight days off, the same problem happened even with the power cable connected. I had to reboot about 6 times until success.

edited III (June 14): I can boot (even with battery) if I disconnect the cable and take off the battery for a few seconds. This lead me to conclude that maybe something is kept into memory of some hardware. 
Maybe or maybe not related but I also have touchpad issues (jumps) with this machine.

edited IV (June 25): I opened gconf-editor and went to apps > gnome-power-manager and disabled everything possibly related to suspend or hibernate. No help.
Also I grabbed a Fedora live usb pendrive and got the same problem:

[image]

So I think it is a hardware problem related issue.

Comment: Wow. That ain't pretty. Do you have any other working OS's on that machine?

Comment: No other OS,  just Natty.

Comment: looks like a suspend/hibernate issue to me.

Comment: @Takkat Hello how are you? Thank you, I will look if it can be related to this.

Comment: No trouble to suspend or hibernate.

Comment: I've seen some wifi cards cause these sort of issues - can you pull out/disable in bios to see if this is the cause?

Comment: ... also, various IRQ issues - does booting with noapic or nolapic make any difference?

Comment: This is happening to me when i'm using for a long time VLC... maybe some problem with hibernate/suspend?

Comment: Maybe. I use VLC also. But I can hibernate/suspend without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix but not an explanation therefore help still needed here ;-)

**The Fix**
Disconnect the cable and take off the battery for a few seconds.

**Conjectures**
This fix lead me to conclude that maybe something is kept into memory of some hardware. 
Maybe or maybe not related but I also have touchpad issues (jumps) with this machine (that isn't solved with the take off of battery procedure).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look inside `log file viewer` (press <kbd>super</kbd> and type "log file viewer") and see if you can find error messages prior to the bad_area_nosemaphore in your screenshot.

bad_area_nosemaphore: one of the causes for this can be faulty memory. That can also explain why you sometimes have a problem: if that bad memory is not touched everything works like a charm. If it does get touch unexpected results can be expected. In general: irregular behaviour during boot always start thinking memory 1st.

So run memtest from the live cd or from grub if you can boot into it and see if 1 of your memory modules is in bad shape and if so replace it.

Comment: Thank you very much Rinzwind. But (fortunately?) memory test seems to be ok.

Comment: Try compile linux kernel, it's the best memory test I ever seen. If you get segfault - memory is bad.

Comment: @Extender I will try it. Thank you very much.  @Rinzwind: I could not find the errors messages showed in the picture :-/

Comment: @Rinzwind I couldn't find anything at log file viewer. The errors seams that weren't recorded :-(

Comment: @Extender no problem compiling a kernel... Maybe another hardware fault, not ram?

Comment: I'm out of options _O- sorry.

Comment: No problem. I still appreciate your help. I just hope it's not a hardware bug so I can fix. In a couple of days I will reinstall Natty and see if it happens again. If it does, maybe I can test if it happens with others distros.

Answer (score 3):

If this was from an alpha I would do a clean install, but that's my personal choice.

Having said which, looking at the evidence I would say that the kernel is probably trying to determine settings by probing interrupts or loading a module.

Try turning off the acpi in the grub boot parameters.

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much. I'm curious trying to find the problem, and a little bit afraid of nothing being able to boot if I need. I will search more for a fix before given up and reinstall ;-)

Comment: Well. I've tried both. I've installed a brand new final 11.04 and got the bug again. Then I've added "acpi=off", but unfortunately neither solve the issue. When I plug the energy cable all goes right. :-/ Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: It's been 3 days that the problem didn't happened again, so I think it could be a matter of software bug.

Comment: I thought it was solved but it is not. After spending eight days off, the same problem happened even with the power cable connected. I had to reboot about 6 times until success.