# Ubuntu boots to black screen until battery is removed and reinserted

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, windows-8, uefi

I have a Toshiba laptop that was running Windows 8.  I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and deleted Windows 8 in the install.  Ubuntu worked fine until I shut the PC down.  When I tried to start it again it would just go to a black screen.  If I take the battery out of the PC and put it back in and turn the PC on Ubuntu will work.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem with one HP Laptop (Pavilion dv6) for more then 2 years look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42637/boot-failure-randomly-can-someone-help). What I have discovered so far:

1) Buying another battery doesn't fix the problem,
2) Taking out the battery with the cable connected also doesn't fix it,
3) I have to be careful not to disconnect the power cable when the laptop is shutting down,
4) I have to be super careful not to connect the power cable when the laptop is booting up (but connecting it after the boot seems ok),
5) I got more successful boots with the power cable disconnected,
6) I tried some grub acpi configurations without success.

So I've settled. The two most important steps seems to be the numbers "3" and "4".

Best regards.

Comment: I was going to suggest something along the line of number 6.

Comment: Please update initramfs and the tell-me if you keep having that problem. Use "sudo update-initramfs -u"

Comment: I have found some information here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs .I will be able to test this on Wednesday, but I am thinking that I already have tested three brand new installations (11.04, 11.10, 12.04), and I can't see why `sudo update-initramfs -u` should work. Any tips?

Comment: I've just updated the initramfs let's hope for the best ;-)

Comment: One week has passed without this issue. Let's keep observing.

Comment: It happened again. And it happened also with another laptop. I am wondering what kind of care I am not aware of that may be causing this.